# Handling input focus in sibling, or distantly related, React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

```
A
|-B
| |-C
|   |-D
|
|-E
  |-input
```

I have a component D which is on a separate, deeper, branch of the component tree as component E. When a certain action happens in D (or anywhere in the stack), I want to focus an input in E. Do I need to store a global reference to the input somehow using `ref` or is there some better approach to control document focus across distant elements using sagas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems kinda ad-hoc without knowing the exact details, but here's how I would achieve it -

1) "A" stores "isEInputFocused" as state

2) "A" has a function to switch the above state value (on/ off) and pass this function down as prop to any other components that wanna trigger focus/ blur on "E". E.g.

```
state = {
    isEFocused: false,
};

toggleEFocus() {
    this.setState({ isEFocused: !this.state.isEFocused });
}

render() {
    <div>
        <D toggleEFocused={ ::this.toggleEFocus } />
        <E isEFocused={ this.state.isEFocused } />
    </div>
}
```

(the double colon is to bind the function so it can access "A" state correctly)

3) "E" then receives this as a prop from "A". Also in "E" *componentWillReceiveProps*, trigger input focus based on aforementioned prop.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isEFocused) this._inputRef.focus();
    else this._inputRef.blur();
    // this._inputRef is the ref to the input in E
}
```

4) Now in "D", when certain action happens, just trigger *toggleEFocus()* that is passed down from "A"